# Tapi3lib.ITAddress does not return all devices

Tags: c#, tapi

In an effort to automate some phone calling processes and integrate TAPI3 with another application, I am using to following code that was found as a sample;

```
tapi = new TAPI3Lib.TAPIClass();
tapi.Initialize();
foreach (TAPI3Lib.ITAddress ad in (tapi.Addresses as TAPI3Lib.ITCollection)) 
        cbLines.Items.Add(ad.AddressName);
```

This code fills the devices in a dropdown and the dropdown only contains one device and it only shows from my computer. I tried installing the PIMphony_6.8_bld3200_XX_Alcatel on other computers where i add the IP address of the PBX device and a phone number (ex: 106) but it does not even show in the list the one device that i can see on my computer. I whatsoever have no idea what and how i managed to be able to see the device on my computer when i run this code. Obviously i am missing something. The devices we are using are Alcatel and the phone can be controlled by this app only on my computer. (i can provide the zip file containing PIMphony_6.8_bld3200_XX_Alcatel if needed). So the ultimate goal is to be able to see telephone lines on all computers so we can control them from the computer.

What am i missing Tapi3 experts? is it a missing installation on the other pc's ? and why only my device shows up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 3rd party TAPI driver installed, it might be on a DVD with the PBXor on some support website, but some manufacturers charge extra for it. This PIMphony looks like a phone control tool but that does not guarantee it is using TAPI  under the hood, it may be using some propitiatory protocol.

I don't know TAPI3 but if you use TAPI correctly you should see 3 to 4 standard windows builtin devices (like WAN miniports) even if you have no drivers installed.

You need a decent test tool to compare results with, I would recommend phone.exe, it is kind of the standard test tool in the TAPI business. But it's getting harder to find online these days, here is a link to a slighly extended variant that google got me quickly: https://helpdesk.estos.de/Knowledgebase/Article/View/82/3/howto-ephoneexe--tapi-test-tool

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried the suggested application and it still only returns one line and that is my line. Which makes me think if there is a configuration needed on the PBX to kind of "enable" it to show on the network or something similar. I will consult the company that installed the PBX and inform you of the outcome.

Comment: There is no configuration on the PBX to show or hide the devices. The employee has no idea why that happens. Back to square 1!

Comment: Check the local driver settings: Control Panel > Phone and Modem > Advanced tab > Select Vendor driver and press Configure. (Note: on some windows version you need to specifically search the control panel for the Phone and Modem item, because it does not show it by default)

Comment: Coming back to notify that indeed it was a wrong driver installed. With my 0 knowledge on this project back in the day i now see how different PBXs interact with various either universal drivers or their own driver versions. Thanks again Kris you have been extremely valuable